# Using ElectricImp server.show() and Arduino

Tags: arduino, uart, imp

I'm following the [sparkfun tutorial for connecting an arduino to electric imp](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/397). I only have one arduino and imp, so I'm trying to get whatever I type in the arduino serial monitor to display in the imp node using `server.show()`.

I've modified one of the functions in the sparkfun code to look like this:

```
function pollUart()
{
    imp.wakeup(0.00001, pollUart.bindenv(this));  // schedule the next poll in 10us

    local byte = hardware.uart57.read();  // read the UART buffer
    // This will return -1 if there is no data to be read.

    while (byte != -1) // otherwise, we keep reading until there is no data to be read.
    {
        // server.log(format("%c", byte));  // send the character out to the server log. Optional, great for debugging
        // impeeOutput.set(byte);  // send the valid character out the impee's outputPort

        server.show(byte)
        byte = hardware.uart57.read();  // read from the UART buffer again (not sure if it's a valid character yet)
        toggleTxLED();  // Toggle the TX LED
    }
}
```

`server.show(byte)` is only displaying seemingly random numbers. I have an idea of why this is, I just don't know how to fix it because I'm not that familiar with UARTs and squirrel.

`local byte = hardware.uart57.read();` reads in the ascii characters from the arduino in byte form (I think), and they're not being 'translated' into their ascii characters before I use `server.show(byte)`.
How do I do this in squirrel?
Also, I think polling every 10us is the wrong way to go here. I'd like to only poll when there's new information, but I also don't know how to do that in squirrel. Can someone point me to an example where this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to connect your Electric Imp to Wireless router as i wasn't able to configure Electric Imp with my wifi router.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the wrong data type to the show method of the server object.  The electric imp [docs](http://devwiki.electricimp.com/doku.php?id=electricimpapi%3aserver%3ashow) state that it takes a string, `server.show(string)`.  I think that `local` is the correct type to receive the value from `hardware.uart57.read()`.  You can tell from the [docs](http://devwiki.electricimp.com/doku.php?id=electricimpapi%3auart%3aread) as well.  So, you need to find a way to cast your byte to a string.  I bet you could find the answer [here](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/#documentation).  From what I read Squirrel use's Unicode so there is a probably a function that takes Unicode bytes and loads them into a string object.